# How to make android app compatible with lower versions from 6.0

Tags: android

I am using api 23 and my app doesn't work on lower versions. Please suggest any solution for creating compatibility with lower versions in android studio.

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file or make sure your `minSdkVersion` is below `23` to support lower version device.

Comment: Your question is not complete, please explain why your version is not compatible with api < 23. Post some code, build.gradle file or errors.

Answer (score 3):

In build.gradle

Change minSdkVersion to the version you want it to work.

example

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myname.myprj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the minimum version of API on which you want to run your application in your **app** module's `build.gradle` file right under **defaultConfig** section

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.me"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Check it out, maybe right now it may be 23 or something, This **minSdkVersion** decides the minimum number above which application can run.